# Using correct multithreading in a game

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently developing a 3D game which should simulate deformable 3D objects. With deformable, I mean that the geometry of the 3D object is changing from frame to frame. In the game is a rendering loop which should get executed as often as possible (at least 30 times/second) to get a descend frame rate. But I'm also doing two other things in this rendering loop: Calculating new geometry and calculating an axis aligned bounding box hierarchy (AABVH). I need the AABVH for collision detection. It is very important that the geometry and AABVH calculations are complete before the 3D object gets rendered. Calculating the new geometry and AABVH is a time consuming task so my frame rate drops rapidly. My idea was therefore to calculate the AABVH in a seperate thread.
This looks like this:

```
Thread t;
public void Render(Object3D o) // renders 3D object
{
  if (t != null) // wait until the new geometry got calculated
  {
     t.Join();
  }
  o.RenderGeometry();
  t = new Thread(() => o.CalcAABVH());
  t.Start();
}
```

I'm not an experte in parallel programming in C# but I'm sure that this is not a good solution. Every frame, a new Thread gets created, executed and destroyed which causes a big overhead. How would a good solution look like in my case?

Comment: What platform is this on? OpenGL? DirectX 11? Could you do the geometry modifications in a shader on the GPU? Could you simplify the deformation meshes to make this more reasonable and in cooperation with the GPU, e.g. using skinned meshes? Multi-threading is very complicated, you really want to avoid it until it's absolutely necessary. Modern DX makes this somewhat easier, since you can access the DX resources from multiple threads etc., but it's still quite hard. If you do need multi-threading, Gusdor's suggestion is a great way to avoid most of the complexities.

Comment: Be careful; multi-threading will not necessarily improve the performance of your application.  A significant performace gain will only be achievable if you have multiple CPU cores and ensure your threads get scheduled on different cores.  Obviously, hardware graphics accelerators are a great way to achieve this.  :-)

Comment: @Luaan: Its OpenGL on Windows. You are right with saying that its costly and complicated to get it right. The problem is that I'm not only calculating new geometry, but also calculating an axis aligned bounding box hierarchy for the new geometry. And I can't use geometry shaders for that.

Comment: @MikeofSST: Absolutely true! Hardware graphics accelerators? Never heard of that. Whats this?

Comment: Sorry I was not precise enough. I'm actually calculating two things: the new geometry and a bounding volume hierarchy. I edited my question already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not block the rendering of the next frame while the geometry is updated. You may as well run the calculation synchronously. Blocking the rendering will increase the total render time for each frame and have a negative impact on framerate - an effect you are specifically trying to avoid!

Instead, use a flag to indicate if the calculation of new geometry is ongoing and if it is, render the old geometry. Now you need 2 geometry sets - much like with a framebuffer, you swap them when the new geometry is complete.

The net effect will be that some frames may not have the latest geometry available when you wish it would be. This will be more noticeable on objects where the geometry takes longer to calculate. Most of graphic programming for games is smoke and mirrors anyway so don't worry about it.

### Implementation

Please use a threadpool thread for these update operations as the cost of creation is less expensive. Ideally, use the task parallel library. As a bonus, a `Task` object tracks its running status for you!

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    ...

    Task t;
    public void Render(Object3D o) // renders 3D object
    {
        if(t != null && t.Status == System.Threading.Tasks.TaskStatus.Running)
        {
            //render old geometry
        }
        else
        {
            t = Task.Factory.StartNew(o.CalcNewGeometry())
                    .ContinueWith(p => o.UpdateGeometry); //swap the new geometry in
        }
    }
```

You will need some synchronization here to make sure that you do not swap in your new geometry whilst you are rendering the old geometry. I will leave that up to you.

Comment: Rendering the old geometry might not be an option if the OP wants a fixed-step simulation of e.g. a bouncing ball. Still, this will at least allow him to use the thread-pool to schedule work, and to actually schedule the work even before the last frame started processing if need be, which might help the latency significantly.

Comment: @Luaan arguably, if you want a fixed step simulation, you do you steps synchronously: `Calculate physics -> calculate geometry -> render`. Accuracy is more important than framerate. This looks like entity based game programming to me and I stuck with that theme.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the usual way. You can easily shave off a ms or two of latency if you start the processing earlier in the `Update` step, though, which can help the FPS a lot. After all, the OPs solution is already lagging a frame behind any input - he's computing the next geometry after rendering the last one.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm not a multithreading expert. But I'm  sure that I will get a NullReferenceException with you solution because t is null when the if clause gets reached the first time. So I have to create a task beforehand and not in the else clause, right?

Comment: @NMO that would force geometry to draw each pass. I've edited a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I implemented it that way. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading in games is **mostly**(depending on genre, features,...) used this way:

- 1 Thread - Rendering
- 1..x Threads - Physics (where your deformations would belong)
- x Threads - AI

Render the actual state of the object, deform it in a copy in the physic thread(s).
Switch objects after deforming as proposed by *Gusdor*.

I would propose you use something like the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to queue the objects that should be calculated by the physic thread(s). That way you don't need to recreate the threads everytime. Just let them idle and calculate in the moment something enters the queue.